# Get dependencies from resolve configuration on Gradle 4.1

Tags: android, gradle

On previous versions of android plugin for Gradle I could, with my own task, take the path of the jar dependencies using this:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    task "copyDependencies${variant.name.capitalize()}"(type: Copy) {
        configurations.compile.files().each { dependency ->
            from dependency.path
        }
        into project.projectDir.path + "/build/libs/${variant.name}"
    }
}
```

But in the latest version of this plugin, `compile` pass to deprecated and they introduced `api` and `implementation` configurations, so when I try to use the previous code, gradle said that:

> Resolving configuration 'api' directly is not allowed

Any suggestion for this new change introduced?

---

**UPDATE**

I have got a dependencies list and filter for configurations doing this:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    task "copyDependencies${variant.name.capitalize()}"(type: Copy) {
        from {
            variant.getCompileConfiguration().files().each { dependency ->
                configurations.api.getDependencies().each { configDep ->
                    if (dependency.name.contains(configDep.name)) {
                        from dependency.path
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        into project.projectDir.path + "/build/libs/${variant.name}"
    }
}
```

But this solution still has problems, in addiction when project B is dependent on project A. Both with this task defined, Gradle doesn't build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution for copy dependencies from a configuration:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    task "copyDependencies${variant.name.capitalize()}"() {
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        doLast {
            println "Executing from in copyDependencies${variant.name.capitalize()}"
            variant.getCompileConfiguration().getAllDependencies().each { dependency ->
                configurations.api.getDependencies().each { configDep ->
                    if (dependency.name.contains(configDep.name)) {
                        println "Dependency detected: " + dependency.name
                        variant.getCompileClasspath().each { fileDependency ->
                            if (fileDependency.absolutePath.contains(dependency.name)) {
                                println fileDependency.absolutePath
                                copy {
                                    from fileDependency.absolutePath
                                    into project.projectDir.path + "/build/intermediates/bundles/${variant.name}/libs"
                                    exclude '**/classes.jar'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please see [chapter 48.4](https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) of the userguide to find all available configurations and which are to be consumed and / or resolved.

Comment: I know that I can't resolve it with this configuration, what I wanted to know is how to get the path of every dependency marked with 'api' configuration. I need that task continue working.

Comment: Did you even look at my link? I think `apiElements` is what you are after which is described there.